# Fast xor array in matlab

Tags: matlab, xor

Is there a fatser way to xor every column of a matrix than this?

```
mod(sum(matrix),2)
```

It converts from logical to double and uses the expensive modulo.

Update:

According to [this source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246073), summing uint's is slower than summing doubles because it involves max clipping and other reasons. 
Also, note that summing logicals (with `'native'`) stops at 1.

Comment: The `xor` function?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @reve_etrange, what I am looking for is to xor the elements of an array A: A(1) xor A(2) xor ... xor A(n). Matlab's xor(A,B) doesn't do it.

Comment: I'd write a mex function to do it if you want it fast.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to avoid the cast to `double` but it's not better (often worse).

```
A = rand(2000000, 1) > 0.5;
 class(A)

tic
B = mod(sum(A),2)
toc

tic
C = mod(sum(uint32(A),'native'),2)
toc

tic
D = bitand(sum(uint32(A),'native'),1)
toc
```

The `native` option of sum allow you to keep the type of the argument in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @ClementJ says, I tried

```
tic
E = A(1)
for i = 2:numel(A)
    E = xor(y, A(i));
end
E
toc
```

hoping the accelerator would help, but it doesn't (much), and

```
tic
F = num2cell(A);
F = xor(F{:})
toc
```

which doesn't actually work because XOR only allows 2 inputs.

MATLAB's double precision vector arithmetic is about as fast as it gets, so you probably can't do better. If this is really driving your performance, then I suggest writing a C-MEX function: should be easy.