# How do I perform XOR in MATLAB for two vectors?

Tags: matlab

Try this

```
>> A = [1 2];
>> B = [1 4];
>> xor(A, B)

ans =

     0     0
```

How? Where's the mistake?

Comment: Try setting one of those numbers to zero. Non-zero numbers may be truthy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the bitwise XOR:

```
>> A = [1 2]
>> B = [1 4]
>> C = bitxor(A, B)
>> C

C =

     0     6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is, that matlab treats everything != 0 as true. And as we know

```
true xor true -> false.
```

Perhaps [Fast xor array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721775/fast-xor-array-in-matlab) can help you.